# Server-side Flex/AIR app possible?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, mxml, server-side

Are there any clean ways to implement a server-side Flex/AIR app? The basic idea is that a large Flex app would run off a server. A user would then see client-side only the current view of the Flex app and be able to interact with it. The interactions would be sent to the server, and it would process them accordingly. The overall goal of this is to not force the client to download a very large Flex app just to use the application.

Comment: In additional to RSLs which can be used to make your Flex app's size smaller, you can also use Modules which are bits loaded at runtime.  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=modular_5.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. And this is a ridiculous idea. Why wouldn't you just use Flashplayer as a delivery device?

You will bog down the server. No way you'd want to manage flex app instances. NO. do not do this. What, you gonna give each person an RDP to a virtual server running it's own flex app? hahahahahahah

if you need collaboration, setup an RTMP server.

Comment: Yes, I guess so - easy enough just to load a .swf containing the functionality a user needs when they need it.

Comment: RSL is your friend. http://old-wp.slekx.com/2010/01/flash-cs4-runtime-shared-library-tutorial/

Comment: Well, I agree this is a ridiculous idea; but using the socket functionality of Adobe AIR; there is no reason you couldn't write a server. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html . Unless you want to develop skill in network communications and how servers work; I wouldn't recommend trying to build a server from scratch; as there are plenty out there to fit any purpose.